# Deus Ex:GOTY crashes on the "BatteryPark" level

Tags: pc, deus-ex

My problem is a rather simple one:
When running Deus Ex: GOTY on Steam, the game crashes when in the Battery Park level, near the vent section, leaving a critical error message:

[image: Critical Error! Runaway loop detected]

I'm running the game on Linux through Proton 4.11.
I tried running Deus Ex in safe mode, but the game still crashed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fix [here](http://kentie.net/article/dxguide/index.htm):

- Start the game using the `-hax0r` parameter in the launch options. This enables cheat mode.
- In-game, using the console, press <kbd>t</kbd>, remove the `say` that's entered by default on a new command line, and type `playersonly`. This will freeze all other entities, only to temporarily prevent them from running right into problems again, giving you more time to terminate the buggy entity.
- Type `killall deusex.terrorist` to eliminate the faulty entities in your current game.
- Type `playersonly` again to resume normal play.

Alternatively, try out the replacement executable (neatly named *Deus Exe*) from that same link.

Comment: Nope. I typed "playersonly" when loading into the save and it still crashed, while I was typing "killall deusex.terrorist19".

Comment: Now I tried `killall deusex.terrorist` after `playersonly` and the game still crashed. I can confirm this time I was fast enough.

Comment: Should I expect something to pop up when I successfully type in a command?

Comment: I've already tried it multiple times, but none worked, they all returned the same error.

Comment: Indeed... Strange.

Comment: @Psionikal And the second option, to exchange the executable?

Comment: Gives me a new error, "Can't find Class in file 'Class DeusEx.ConWindowActive'

Comment: After some quick testing, turned out I had to do the "playersonly" trick after replacing the installer. Problem solved, thanks for the support.